# Leaflet - The label binded to a marker is not always in the same position when zooming

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a problem with the labels binded to some markers when zooming in and out. In the following pictures you can see an example of the problem:

[image][image][image][image]

As you can see when I zoom in the label is always closer to my marker. The problem is that I always want it to be as the last picture, that is simply under my marker.

Here is my code:

```
var myPos = new L.latLng(lat, lon); //lat and lon are coordinates defined above

var markerMyPos = L.marker(myPos, {
    icon: myIcon
});

markerMyPos.bindLabel('Some text', { noHide: true, className: 'marker_label', direction: 'right', offset: [-70, 0] }).addTo(map);
```

This happens mostly when I am at a low level of zoom and go down fast, instead if I am already at a high level of zoom and zoom more then the labels are nearer to the marker...

Comment: I assume you are using the Leaflet-label plugin? The readme isn't clear about the `offset` param, but I think it might be possible that the offset is too  large to fit in the map when the marker is at the lower end. Try a smaller offset then or use the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the css label..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/css/leaflet.label.css" />
```

Sorry so stupid of me..